# Shiny app for prediction with rpart displaying error

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to build a shiny app. The objective was to let user input a csv file in a input box. Then user can input a dependent variable name in text box. The main panel will display the summary details of model fit and plot.

I have coded the following as **ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(h1("ANALYSIS",align = "center")),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

        fileInput('file1', 'Select CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
        textInput("text", label = strong("Dependent Variable"), 
                  value = "Enter Dependent Variable...")
    ),
    mainPanel(br(),

              textOutput('text1'),
              plotOutput('plot')
        )
        )
))
```

The following as server.R :

```
 library(shiny)
 library(rpart)
 library(rpart.plot)

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
    data <-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,  quote=input$quote)
    depVar <- input$text
    modrpart <- rpart(depVar ~. ,data=data)
    modrpart
    #depVar


})

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        data <-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,  quote=input$quote)
        depVar <- input$text
        modrpart <- rpart(depVar ~. ,data=data)
        prp(modrpart)
    })


})
```

When RunApp is called, its showing error "Error in !: invalid argument type".
The model details and plot is not displayed in main panel as intended. I am missing something . I have used https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ByEpXfdtGWMjZHUGpNc3ZZSTg for test. Thanks

Comment: can you upload .csv somewhere please

Comment: Thanks @PorkChop . There is a input box. You may select any small csv  file availble, in input box of sidebarPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I created a reactive dataset `data` in which there is a requirement that the dataset is uploaded `req(inFile)`. It will prevent error propagation due to missing inputs.

```
data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    req(inFile)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,  quote=input$quote)
    data
  })
```

After that I created another reactive for your model with a requirement that the inputed name of the dependent variable is a valid variable. Since `input$text` is a string, you have to create a formula with `paste0` and `as.formula` functions to be able to train the model. You also pass your reactive dataset via `data()` to the model. (These two reactives allow you to not repeat the code unnecessarily)

```
model <- reactive({
    req(input$text %in% names(data() ))
    depVar <- input$text
    mod <- as.formula(paste0(depVar, " ~ ."))
    modrpart <- rpart(mod, data = data() )
    modrpart
  })
```

Finally, you can pass the model via `model()` to `render*` functions.

Note that I changed `renderText` to `renderPrint` otherwise it would yield an error. (renderText cannot handle "cat" function)

---

You got this error: "Error in !: invalid argument type" because you had missing widgets and there was no `input$header` and few others. I fixed it by adding them. (this simple upload interface is taken from [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html)

`read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,  quote=input$quote)`

---

**EDITED** on a request in a comment:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    req(inFile)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,  quote=input$quote)
    data
  })

  # reactive test data
  testdata <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file2
    req(inFile)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })

  model <- reactive({
    req(input$text %in% names(data() ))
    depVar <- input$text
    mod <- as.formula(paste0(depVar, " ~ ."))
    modrpart <- rpart(mod, data = data() )
    modrpart
  })

  output$text1 <- renderPrint({ # changed to renderPrint
    model()
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    prp(model() )
  })

  # print predictions to the console
  observe({ 
    pred <- predict(object = model(), newdata = testdata() )
    print(head(pred, 10))
  })

})


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(h1("ANALYSIS",align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput('file1', 'Upload Train Data',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"'),
      br(),
      textInput("text", label = strong("Dependent Variable"), 
                value = "Enter Dependent Variable..."),

      # new fileInput
      br(),
      fileInput('file2', 'Upload Test Data', 
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv'))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      textOutput('text1'),
      plotOutput('plot')
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @UnnamedUser. I was trying a bit on this. I have added another fileInput box where an user can select a test data. I created another reactive dataset 'testdata'. Now I tried to predict with the model fit object. This is giving errors. I suppose  an upload a test data or the original data to get the predictions. Since original is stored in a reactive dataset already. I suppose its producing errors. Can you pls show the process.