# Conditional Statement in Shiny not displaying values

Tags: r, shiny

I have coded a shiny app. It have user input dataset and user input dependent variable .It predicts the dependent variable.
Dependent variable is stored in input$text

In UI.R :

```
textOutput('contents2')
```

In server.R I have mentioned a conditional statement where if the dependent variable is factor , it will predict class levels, otherwise continuous values:

```
      output$contents2 <- renderText({
        if(class(input$text)=="factor"){
            predict(modelc(), newdata=testdata(),type="class")}

        if(class(input$text)=="numeric"){
                predict(model(), newdata=testdata())  

        }
   })
```

But its not displaying predicted values. I was wondering what might be missing. Thanks

Comment: `modelc()`, `model()` and `testdata()` appear to be functions (should be data or a model object). Is this really what you are after?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik This is continuation of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116546/shiny-app-for-prediction-with-rpart-displaying-error/39121161?noredirect=1#comment65595711_39121161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing gets printed because no value is returned by `renderText`, you can easily fix it by wrapping `predict(...)` into `return` function.

However, there is another bug. Since `input$text` is a character string its class is `character` and your logical comparison doesn't do what you want. You can fix it, first by subsetting `testdata()` with `[[` operator which gives you a vector and then checking its class.

You also have to make sure that the name of inputed variable is indeed a valid variable - as usual with `req` function (or `validate` and `need`)

---

**Full example:**

```
output$contents2 <- renderText({

  req(input$text %in% names(testdata() ))
  test <- class(testdata()[[input$text]])

  if (test == "factor") {
    return(predict(modelc(), newdata = testdata(), type = "class") )
  }
  if (test == "numeric") {
    return(predict(model(), newdata = testdata()) )
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @UnnamedUser. The predicted vector for classification is printing 1,1,2,3,1,..  Instead can I modify it to printing the class level names.